# How to install Matlab on linux server without admin rights

Tags: sudo, matlab

I want to install Matlab on the Ubuntu server where I don't have admin privileges. When I run `sudo ./install` from downloaded Matlab's folder it say `user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`
How to install Matlab on any server or system without admin right access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

> `./install`

And follow the installation wizard to complete the installation.
You have to select the **destination folder**, which you can select or create in your home directory. e.g.

> /home/ur_user/MATLAB

After the installation process completed, you might need to activate it. Your activation file will be in the bin folder; use the terminal to open the folder and run the following code:

> `./activate_matlab.sh` .

To launch Matlab use:

> `./matlab` (while being in the bin folder)

I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks, how can I save desktop icon for Matlab?

Comment: Create launcher with `matlab -desktop` filepath.